# Canvas Admin Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

Using Canvas admin which pulls in Jquery Datatable. It initializes it along with all the javascript it uses with:

```
if ($.fn.dataTable) 
{ 
    $('.data-table').dataTable (
    { 
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    }); 
};
```

In an include.

I'd like to customize an instance of it on a specific page using:

```
$('#properties').dataTable (
{
     "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "aaSorting": [[2,'asc'], [1,'asc']]
});
```

However I get an error: `DataTables warning (table id = 'properties'): Cannot reinitialize DataTable.`

How do I have it included on every page with the default settings, but then adjust specific instances of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to do something like this:

```
if ($.fn.dataTable) { 
    $('.data-table:not(#properties)').dataTable ({ 
        "bJQueryUI": true, 
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
};

$('#properties').dataTable ({ 
    "bDestroy": true, 
    "bPaginate": false, 
    "aaSorting": [[2,'asc'], [1,'asc']]
});
```

That has the potential to get messy if you have a lot of one-off tables with different options.

The other option would be to instead of recreating the dataTable for `#properties`, you look at the API for the plugin and figure out how to change the options after it's been created.